# Hibernate throws exception although the query is working from db console

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I'm executing rather complex like this :

```
session.createSQLQuery("query").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CheckIn.class));
```

I'm using couple of `AS`(ex: select column `as` columnName from my Table) in my query and hibernate always throws this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for inputrecords on class com.letmedical.store.CheckIn
    at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.hql.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultList(CustomLoader.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at com.letmedical.store.Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

But there are setters for each class field. What do I do? google doesn't help much since this is not strictly hibernate error.

Update :

I tried to iterate trough result list :

```
List<CheckIn> list = query.list();  


for (CheckIn object : list) {
                System.out.println(object.getAppTime());
            }
```

I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.letmedical.store.CheckIn
    at com.letmedical.store.Test.main(Test.java:41)
```

But all attributes of my object are inside this object but I can't cast it to my object CheckIn. Anyone had this issue?

**Update II :**

Here is getter/setter :

```
private Integer inputRecords;

public Integer getInputRecords() {
    return inputRecords;
}
public void setInputRecords(Integer inputRecords) {
    this.inputRecords= inputRecords;
}
```

My Hibernate mapping :

```
  <property name="inputRecords" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="inputRecords" not-null="false" />
        </property>
```

table column is named `inputrecords`

**is there a way arround?**

Comment: please post the CheckIn class...at least the setters/getters.  I suspect you do not have java-bean style setters/getters.  or enable field level access, so hibernate won't even use the setter/getter.

Answer (score 1):

from your stacktrace, you have a field 'inputrecords'.  This should be

```
inputRecords
```

and the setter should be

```
public void setInputRecords(...){
...
}
```